# Bash script is printing wrong characters in my variable

Tags: bash, awk

I'm trying out the following thing in my terminal:

```
spark 0 76 100 | awk '{print substr($0,4,3)}'
```

outputs:

```
▆
```

If I do:

```
GRAPH=$(spark 0 25 100 | awk '{print substr($0,4,3)}')
printf "%s" $GRAPH
```

I get:

```
▂%
```

But looks more like:

[image: how character looks]

As you can see, the `%` appears to be inside a black bar...

How can I get it to print out:

```
▂
```

Without the unexpected % in the same line?

Comment: A couple of comments.  (1) What is `spark`?  I’ve never heard of it, and I didn’t find any reference to it in Super User (in a quick search).  The more information you can give about your problem and your situation (within reason), the easier it is for us to help you.  (2) One of the cardinal rules of testing/debugging/troubleshooting is to change only one thing at a time.  Why did you use “25” with `printf` and “76” without?  Do the first four lines of your question (… “76” …) have anything to do with the rest of the question?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is to do

```
printf "%s\n" $GRAPH
```

When you capture the output from a command into a shell variable with `$(…)` or `` `…` ``, the last newline is stripped, and `printf "%s" …` (unlike `echo`) does not append a newline by default.  So, when you say `printf "%s" $GRAPH`, you are getting the next shell prompt on the same line as your `printf` output.

Secondly, I advise you to change that to

```
printf "%s\n" "$GRAPH"
```

to protect against certain funny characters showing up in `$GRAPH` –– and you are clearly getting funny characters.

Thirdly, you say, “the `%` appears to be inside a black bar”.  That appears to be *inverse video*, in which foreground and background colors are reversed.  That may be caused by one or some of the characters in `$GRAPH`.  If everything else you do until the end of time is in inverse video, even after you’ve done the above two steps, try

```
printf "%s\n" "$GRAPH"; tput sgr0
```

`tput` exercises terminal-specific functionality; in many cases by writing a string.  `sgr0` is the short name for the `exit_attribute_mode` capability, which sets foreground and background colors back to normal (and turns off underline, blink, and whatever other display attributes your terminal supports).